# Implement Wiki: "API:Get the contents of a page" in Python

Tags: python, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm learning to use Wiki API to get the public information of users. I found the script, ["get_users.py"](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-api-demos/blob/master/python/get_users.py), in MediaWiki-API-demos that can help us get general information, like edit count or email address. However, the personal description on the user page can not be fetched in this way.

(An example is shown below. I want to get the text information like "*I'm not usually active on English Wikipedia. Please refer ...*")

[image]

I found that ["API: Get the contents of a page"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page)  offers an option to achieve that. Because I know nothing about PHP, may I ask is there any way we can get these textual contents using the API in Python?

Thank you a lot for your time in advance!

**Update**:

I'm trying to search for the user information of a user list like the following:
[image]
If I want to search personal statements of them, is there any way we can execute them at once, instead of looping them one by one then inputting into the script? (It comes from the demo: [get_pages_revisions.py](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-api-demos/blob/master/python/get_pages_revisions.py))

(Suppose we want to find the info of Catrope and Bob, the following implementation by modifying `PARAMS` cannot work correctly:

```
PARAMS = {
    "action": "query",
    "prop": "revisions",
    "titles": "User:Catrope|Bob",
    "rvprop": "timestamp|user|comment|content",
    "rvslots": "main",
    "formatversion": "2",
    "format": "json"
}
```

)

Comment: you don't have to know PHP to use information from `API: Get the contents of a page` - there is only URL with extension `.php` - nothing more - and you can use this URL with any language - ie. python `requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Pet_door&prop=text&formatversion=2")`

Comment: BTW: code in `get_users.py` uses also URL with extension `.php` to get data and it doesn't use any PHP code for this.

Comment: BTW: you could add URL to page which has information which you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to know PHP to use information from `API: Get the contents of a page`. There are only URLs with extension `.php` - nothing more - and you can use these URLs with any language - ie. python. Even code in `get_users.py` uses URL with extension `.php` and it doesn't use `PHP` code for this.

You have to only add `&format=json` to get data as `JSON` instead of `HTML`

I don't know which URL you need to get data but you can use it as string

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Pet_door&prop=text&formatversion=2&format=json")

data = r.json()

print(data['parse']['text'])
```

Or you can write params as dictionary - like in `get_users.py` - and it is more readable for user and it is easier to change param

```
import requests

params = {
    'action': 'parse',
#    'page': 'Pet_door',
    'page': 'USER:Catrope',
#    'prop': 'text',
    'prop': 'wikitext',   
    'formatversion': 2,
    'format': 'json'
}

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", params=params)
data = r.json()

#print(data.keys())
#print(data)
#print('---')

#print(data['parse'].keys())
#print(data['parse'])
#print('---')

#print(data['parse']['text'])    # if you use param `'prop': 'text'
#print('---')

print(data['parse']['wikitext']) # if you use param `'prop': 'wikitext'
print('---')

# print all not empty lines
for line in data['parse']['wikitext'].split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()  # remove spaces
    if line: # skip empty lines
        print('--- line ---')
        print(line)

print('---')

# get first line of text (with "I'm not usually active on English Wikipedia. Please refer...")
print(data['parse']['wikitext'].split('\n')[0])
```

Because for `'prop': 'text'` it returns `HTML` then it would need `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to search information in `HTML`. For `'prop': 'wikitext'` it gives text without HTML tags and it was easier to use `split('\n')[0]` to get first line with

```
I'm not usually active on English Wikipedia. Please refer to my [[mw:User:Catrope|user page]] at [[mw:|MediaWiki.org]].
```

---

**EDIT:** It doesn't have method to get all pages in one request. You have to use `for`-loop with `'page': 'USER:{}'.format(name)`

```
import requests

for name in ['Catrope', 'Barek']:
    print('name:', name)

    params = {
        'action': 'parse',

        'page': 'USER:{}'.format(name),  # create page name

    #    'prop': 'text',
        'prop': 'wikitext',   
        'formatversion': 2,
        'format': 'json'
    }

    r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", params=params)
    data = r.json()

    #print(data['parse']['text'])
    print(data['parse']['wikitext'])
    print('---')
```

---

**EDIT:** For `query` `revisions` you have to use full titles

```
 "titles": "User:Catrope|User:Bob|User:Barek",
```

But not titles gives results so you have to check if there is `revisions` in data

```
import requests

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php"

PARAMS = {
    "action": "query",
    "prop": "revisions",
    "titles": "User:Catrope|User:Bob|User:Barek",
    "rvprop": "timestamp|user|comment|content",
    "rvslots": "main",
    "formatversion": "2",
    "format": "json"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
DATA = R.json()

PAGES = DATA["query"]["pages"]

for page in PAGES:
    if "revisions" in page:
        for rev in page["revisions"]:
            print(rev['slots']['main']['content'])
    else:
        print(page)
```

Comment: Hi furas! Thank you a lot for your clear explanation. It's really helpful. So actually the "parameters" I input in the script are just the substring after the PHP link, right? So I can modify it directly. Thank you so much for pointing this out. And for the URL I'm looking for, I just updated my question. Could you mind having a check? Thank you!

Comment: You can change value in `params =  {..}` and it will use this changes when you use it in `requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", params=params)` to create link `"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php??action=parse&page=Pet_door&prop=text&formatversion=2&format=json"`. And I tested `'page': 'USER:Catrope|Bob', you can't get all in one request. You have to check every user in separated request.

Comment: For `query` `revisions` you have to use full titles - like `"titles": "User:Catrope|User:Bob|User:Barek"` But not all titles gives result so you have to check if you get `revisions` - see new code in answer.

Comment: Great! You are perfect! That's all I need. Thank you for your excellent explanations, furas! Have a great week.